# When union and concatenation gives same regular expression

Tags: regular-language, computation-theory

{w∈{0,1}∗|w contains exactly one occurrence of 01}

I get the result by both union and concatenation

1*0*011*0*

OR

(1* U 0*)01(1* U 0*)

how come?

Comment: You don't get the same result; 1001 is in the first set but not the second. Likewise for 0110.

Comment: Note that `L ∪ L = LL` iff `LL = L`. your language does *not* satisfy this condition. I suggest drawing an NFA for `L ∪ L` and `LL` and using Kleene's construction to find the regular expressions describing each.

Answer (score 1):

Your two regular expressions are not equivalent. The first one is correct, and the second one is not. To see the difference, use the distributive property of concatenation:

```
r1 = 1*0*011*0*

r2 = (1* U 0*)01(1* U 0*)
   = 1*011* U 1*010* U 0*011* U 0*010*
```

Note that r2 is the union of four subexpressions which each describes a language. Each of the described languages is a subset of the language of r1:

```
1*0*011*0*    1*0*011*0*    1*0*011*0*    1*0*011*0*    
1*  011*      1*  01  0*      0*011*        0*01  1*
```

Therefore, L(r2) is a subset of L(r1). It has already been pointed out in the comments that L(r1) is not a subset of L(r2), by counterexample (consider string 0110).

To see that r2 is correct, first note that any string in L(r2) is in your language (the only occurrence of 01 is in the middle of the expression, and the expression has to generate it), then argue that any string with exactly one 01 must be generated by this expression. An inductive argument is straightforward and is left as an exercise.